# Python : Create a list of subdirectories

Tags: python

I try to put a listing of subdirectories of a directory into a list.

I use that code :

```
import os

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("W:/test"):
  # print path to all subdirectories first.
  for subdirname in dirnames:
      a= os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)

liste = []
liste.append(a)
print liste
```

The problem is that I have not all my subdirectories into my list **"liste"**

Would you have any solutions ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `liste.append` inside the loop.

```
import os
liste = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for subdir in dirs:
        liste.append(os.path.join(root, subdir))

print(liste)
```